# Set value to property c# datetime error format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, asp.net-core, datetime-format

When you select the data value in a property of the class the following error is generated "Input string not in a correct format".

I'm converting the date as in the image one it generates correct, but when assigning the error is generated.

I converted it to DateTime and also created it as new, but still the error happens.

The same occurs when use  Scheduled = sd,

I am using asp.net core

[image]

Comment: Side note: Should probably be `scheduled = sd`, no need to call `ConvertToDateTime(sd)` as `sd` is already a `DateTime` instance.

Comment: You don't need to convert a `DateTime` to a `DateTime`. The error is complaining about a `string`, so it's probably one of the other items. What are the values at runtime of `collection["CompanyId"]`, `collection["GuardId"]`, and `collection["DriverId"]`? Perhaps you should use `int.TryParse` on those items first, to ensure they have valid values.

Comment: The same occurs when use Scheduled = sd,

Comment: In order for us to properly help you, please include the value of `collection` as well as some sample code and the full stack trace or exception details. As mentioned in the answer below, the exception detail will contain the line that threw the exception, and it's most likely not being thrown at the `Convert.ToDateTime` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Convert.ToDateTime is bothering me, although is not throwing this exception.**

First of all, you should not call Convert.ToDateTime on a date time object. 
it does not throw exception but it does not do any conversion also.

Refer [MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_DateTime_) here.

**2. The exception has clear details that it is failed to convert a string to number**

Stack trace is showing that "System.Number.StringToNumber" conversion failed.

So it is one of the other 3 properties which are string and you are trying to convert them to Int64 or long.

You would know which property by line number if you are running solution in debug mode.

**3.  If your values are integer strings (e.g. "10" ) even then if it is not working, then there is problem in culture settings of machine.**

Please refer the complete [thread here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942460/system-formatexception-occurs-when-attempting-to-convert-a-numeric-str)

It is saying that sometimes your conversion fails from "10" to integer value 10 because some registry settings are not set correctly.  You can correct them by:

> While it is possible to directly edit the value for the problem key,
>   the preferred method is to change the Regional Settings to a different
>   Region/Language and then reset it to the desired setting:
>
> 1. Open the Regional and Language Options applet from the Control Panel.
> 2. Note the Current Format.
> 3. Change the Current Format to English (Australian)
> 4. Click Apply.
> 5. Change the Current Format to the noted format, eg, English (American).
> 6. Click Apply and then click OK.

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: The same occurs when use  Scheduled = sd,

Comment: thats what i was saying, that statement is not causing error.  The error is in rest of the statements where you are converting CompanyId, DriverId or GuardID to long.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The error is on GuardId i used GuardId = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["GuardId"]) ? Convert.ToInt64(collection["GuardId"]) : 0 and solve @Manoj Choudhari Thanks

Comment: I am glad I could provide help.  Please conclude by marking this as answer if you feel this helped you to get your error fixed.